# AutoCompleteTextView Items not Clickable when containing custom view like two textview

Tags: android, android-custom-view, autocompletetextview

**This is custom View layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/newbackrow"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_search_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_search_sport"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_search_sport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**// layour inflate in getview() methode**

view perfectly dispay but its not clickable ,let me suggest where going to wrong or any other

** // autocompletetextview OnItemclicklistener**

```
    search_text.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View myView, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position = "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
}
```

Comment: position is in int convert it into string

Comment: y u using this . please use search_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

Comment: you can take position click in custom adapter, please create a custom adapter